# dbpedia sparql query for Deathplace someone

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to get the Deathplace for a unique language. My query is this but I have errors...

```
SELECT ?place ?placeLabel
     WHERE {
         <https://dbpedia.org/page/Alfonso_XII> rdfs:label ?person
         ?place dbo:deathPlace ?person; 
          rdfs:label ?placeLabel.

        FILTER (LANG(?placeLabel) = "en")    
    }
```

Comment: What errors? Could you post this into this question?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with this query.

1. You are using the URL of the resource, not the URI
2. A place of death links a person to a place, not the other way round.
3. The right URI prefix for deathPlace is `dbp:`
4. Places should be resources indeed but in DBpedia that's a strong assumption
5. Since you don't ask for the person level, it seems you don't need it in the query

```
SELECT ?place ?placeLabel
     WHERE {
          dbr:Alfonso_XII dbp:deathPlace ?place .
OPTIONAL  {?place rdfs:label ?placeLabel .
                    FILTER (LANG(?placeLabel) = "en") }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I put this as an example, because I really need to get someone previously, but I didn't want to put all for do it easy. In my case I wanted to put a python variable called i.e. my_query, and finish with the uri after ''' . Like " ''' %(uri). In this case <https://dbpedia.org/page/Alfonso_XII> is really <%s>.

Comment: @dev2win it doesn't matter, you can just use the query from Ivo with your Python string interpolation. Nevertheless, the URL is still wrong, it is `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alfonso_XII`. IT is always `http` as protocol (not `https`)and always `/resource/` for DBpedia (not `/page/`)

Comment: @Ivo : in general one should prefer the `dbo:` prefix in favor of `dbp` because that is the mapping based property namespace. In the current example there is no such data unfortunately, but that also leads to the fact that `dbp:` related facts are not strongly typed, here the place is just a plain string which is odd as it makes it more difficult to get additional data about a persons death place for example. I'd simply get both and use `coalesce` with preference for `dbo:` based property